# Rename contents of folder A with filenames from contents of folder B?

Tags: rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I have two folders with the same amount of files. I want them to have the same file names even though the files are technically different (high res vs low res, but otherwise the same basic stuff). As an example, folder A may look like:

```
file1  
file2  
file3
```

And folder B, with the more desirable names:

```
File 1 - The stuff  
File 2 - More stuff  
File 3 - Great stuff
```

How can I rename all of the files in folder A with the file names from folder B? Assume they are already in order thanks to a numbering system in the file names.

I have Windows 10 and Linux (Debian) at my disposal.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244666/565747 Does this answer your question ? if not let me know, i'll try to write a script

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── B
    ├── File 1 - The stuff
    ├── File 2 - More stuff
    └── File 3 - Great stuff

2 directories, 6 files
```

In test/dry-run mode:

```
$ cd B
$ for i in *; do lc=${i,,}; lc=${lc/ /}; echo "mv ../A/${lc%% *} => ../A/$i"; done 
mv ../A/file1 => ../A/File 1 - The stuff
mv ../A/file2 => ../A/File 2 - More stuff
mv ../A/file3 => ../A/File 3 - Great stuff
```

To rename for real:

```
$ for i in *; do lc=${i,,}; lc=${lc/ /}; mv ../A/"${lc%% *}" ../A/"$i"; done
```

```
$ cd ..

$ tree
.
├── A
│   ├── File 1 - The stuff
│   ├── File 2 - More stuff
│   └── File 3 - Great stuff
└── B
    ├── File 1 - The stuff
    ├── File 2 - More stuff
    └── File 3 - Great stuff

2 directories, 6 files
```